# Python-Asurv Installation

Tags: python, setup.py

When I try to install `python-asurv` using `setup.py`, (typing "path"\python "path"\setup.py install in the command prompt), I get the following error:

```
building extension "twokm" sources target build\src.win32-2.7\twokmmodule.c does not exist: Assuming twokmmodule.c was generated with "build_src --inplace" command. error: '.\\twokmmodule.c' missing`
```

I am on windows 7 64bit with 32bit python2.7

In the zip file that I downloaded, there is `setup.py`, `asurv.py`, `asurv.pyc`, two licences, a readme, and `twokm.pyf` and `twokm.f`, which I think are in fortran format (don't know anything about fortran). The README just says type python `setup.py` install.

I think that for the `twokm.pyf` and `twokm.f` files I need to use `f2py` to convert them to `.py` files, am I right?

How can I install `python-asurv`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed `numpy` at it is dependency of `python-asurv`

Do `pip install numpy` and then Do `python setup.py install` in the directory you have downloaded.